# Restore Chrome tabs while preserving tab groups, window names, and virtual-desktop positions

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tabs, virtual-desktop

At any given time, I have about 150 tabs open in Chrome. They are organized into different tab groups. These groups are organized into different windows, and I use Chrome's "Name window" feature to assign meaningful names to each window. Finally, the windows are divided among seven different virtual desktops.

I want to be able to save this set of tabs, groups, and windows, and to restore it whenever I please. Specifically, I want to start from a single tab (say, the New Tab window) and restore all tabs and windows while meeting these four conditions:

1. Tab groups restored
2. Window names restored
3. Chrome windows restored to the correct virtual desktop (rather than having all Chrome windows restored to whatever virtual desktop happens to be current).
4. All tabs and windows restored at once. If I had 15 Chrome windows open, I don't want to click 15 times to restore all of them.

Exiting Chrome (Alt-F → X) and immediately opening Chrome again meets conditions 1, 2, and 4, but not 3. And it restores only the tabs and windows from the previous session---not, say, tabs and windows from a session that I had last week.

Is there a Chrome extension that meets the four requirements that I've listed above?

##### What I've tried

- The Session Buddy and Spaces extensions are good, but they don't meet conditions 1-3.
- The OneTab, Tab Groups, and Tablerone extensions may be great for other purposes, but they don't suffice for my purposes.
- I've searched this site and others, but found nothing that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the chrome API doesn't yet support access to the window name so no extension can satisfy your condition #2. Please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1190160